# Creating json from array, problem with loop

Tags: php

I need help in how to remove the last comma from this looped var, please.

```
$image_meta .= "{\"id\":\"".$img_id."\",\"client\":\"".$img_desc."\",\"desc\":\"Test\"},";
```

FireFox doesn't seem to mind it, but IE does.

If there is any way to even get rid of the .= and loop my data in another way, i would be most thankful.

Comment: why don't you use the built in json serializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We would need to see the rest of the script.
But from what I understand of your situation, when you echo $image_meta (after the loop I suppose) you could do one of the two:

```
echo rtrim($image_meta,',');
```

or

```
echo substr($image_meta,0,-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

look at implode:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Just to clarify, I'm guessing your doing something similar to this:

```
$image_meta = '';
foreach($blahs as $blah){
   $image_meta .= "{\"id\":\"".$img_id."\",\"client\":\"".$img_desc."\",\"desc\":\"Test\"},";
}
```

Something like this should work:

```
$image_meta_arr = array();
foreach($blahs as $blah){
   array_push($image_meta, "{\"id\":\"".$img_id."\",\"client\":\"".$img_desc."\",\"desc\":\"Test\"}";
}

$image_meta = implode(',', $image_meta_arr);
```

Comment: I checked the whole implode function, but failed at using it with just that 1 line, any idea how can implant it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$ar_image_meta = array();

for/foreach() // your loop
{
  $ar_image_meta[] = '{"id":"'.$img_id.'","client":"'.$img_desc.'","desc":"Test"}';
}

$image_meta = implode(", ", $ar_image_meta);
```

If your goal is to "convert" a PHP variable to a Javascript one, have a look at [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/json_encode).